# React routing for different parts of app like normal app for users and dashboard for admin

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have problem which I don't know how to fix. I created basic app with pages like: home, contact, products ... But I want to have an isolated part of app for admin, like dashboard. I have problem with routing.

Pages on user module work ok, but when I go to the nested route `/dashboard`, I want to switch pages inside that, like `dashboard/users`, `dashboard/roles`.

Here is the code in `app.js`:

```
return (
<div>
   <Route exact path="/">
      <HomePage></HomePage>
    </Route>
    <Route  path="/dashboard">
      {isLogged && <Dashboard></Dashboard>}
      {!isLogged && <p>U dont have acces for this path.</p>}
    </Route>
</div>
)
```

And this is code in `Dashboard.js`:

```
return <>
<div className="sidebar">
  <MainHeader></MainHeader>
</div>
<div className="content">

  <h1>This is home page od dashboard</h1>
  {/* <Route path="/dashboard/roles">
    <Roles></Roles>
  </Route> */}

  <Route path="/dashboard/users">
    <Users></Users>
  </Route>

  <Route path="/dashboard/roles">
    <Roles></Roles>
  </Route>

</div>
```

When I visit `/dashboard`, I got this [Screenshot of /dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZSxo.png), and that is ok, but when I switch to `/dashboard/roles`, I got this [Screenshot of /dashboard/roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey651.png).

My question is why the content of route `/dashboard/roles` is rendered with content of `/dashboard/`? How can I render different pages inside `/dashboard`, because when I switch to some page in `/dashboard` it always keep the home content which in this situation is: This is home page of dashboard.

I want to got only this basics text like "Roles:" in second screenshot I posted here, without this "This is home page of dashboard". Thank you for all solutions if you can help :)

Comment: you are rendering the dashboard as well as others in the same component and navigate them as your code shows. so, keep them separate components from each other and route them to the root file which may be an index file or app file. Now navigate the user's page or roles page when the user is logged in and pushed them to the accessible route using `useHistory` hook. that's the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a problem that the content of the dashboard renders in the dashboard/roles , First of all you did write in the top of the dashboard This is home page od dashboard and that's the problem you make the h1 global that renders with every route in the dashboard file you have to include this h1 into

```
    <Route path="/dashboard">
    <h1>This is home page od dashboard<h1>
  </Route>
```

I hope I helped you if you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask me